# How to pass data to the model field when saving the form? django form models save

Tags: python, django

get the form and process it in post. It is necessary to save the unique uuid of the record to the model, I do it like this: `formOne.save(related_uuid=related_uuid)`

but doesn't work, the error is - `save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'related_uuid'`

**models**

```
class Orders(models.Model):
    device = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=22, blank=True)
```

**views**

```
class OrderAddView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'orders/order_add.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ... some work code
        return self.render_to_response(context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        formOne = SimpleOrderAddForm(self.request.POST, prefix='one_form')        
        if formOne.is_valid():
            related_uuid = shortuuid.uuid()           
            formOne.save(related_uuid=related_uuid)            
            return HttpResponseRedirect('orders_home')
        else:
            print('NotValid')
            return self.form_invalid(formOne, **kwargs)

    def form_invalid(self, formOne,, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        ... some work code
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming that "shortuuid.uuid()" return correct uuid; try

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
formOne = SimpleOrderAddForm(self.request.POST, prefix='one_form')        
if formOne.is_valid():
    a=formOne.save(commit=False) 
    a.related_uuid=shortuuid.uuid()         
    a.save()            
    return HttpResponseRedirect('orders_home')
else:
    print('NotValid')
    return self.form_invalid(formOne, **kwargs)
```